# After changing UseState Hook React component not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am new at React and i am trying to develop a login page. I did almost all but I could not re-render after successful login. I need to refresh the page to see the protected content. As far as I know, using custom Hook and changing its value should trigger a component re-render but although I change the value of it (token), page is not re-rendered. What is the point i missed?

```
//App.js

function App() {
  const { token, setToken } = useToken();
  if(!token) {
    return <Login setToken={setToken} />
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Application</h1>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//UseToken.js

export default function useToken() {
  const getToken = () => {
    const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken;
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

  const saveToken = userToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken.token);
  };

  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token
  }
}
```

```
//Login.js

async function loginUser(credentials) {
  return fetch('http://localhost:8080/user', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
  }).then(data => data.json())
  .then(response => response.token)
 }

export default function Login({ setToken }) {
  const [username, setUserName] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const token = await loginUser({
      username,
      password
    });
    setToken(token);
  }

  return(
    <div className="login-wrapper">
      <h1>Please Log In</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          <p>Username</p>
          <input type="text" onChange={e => setUserName(e.target.value)}/>
        </label>
        <label>
          <p>Password</p>
          <input type="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
        </label>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

Login.propTypes = {
  setToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

```
//Dashboard.js
export default function Dashboard() {
  const logout = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Dashboard</h2>
      <button type="button" onClick={logout}>Logout</button> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you able to maybe create a [mre] so that we can help debug the issue, there are some tools online to help with that for react apps such as [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In useToken.js

```
  const saveToken = userToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken.token);
  }
```

should be replaced to

```
  const saveToken = userToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken); //userToken.token changed to userToken
  }
```

Because, there is no variable named as 'token' in userToken object. It is token itself. So the hook thinks that there is no change and because of that it does not re-render.